# unsuccessful installation of python-weka-wrapper3

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, weka

I just want to install python-weka-wrapper3 package and I get the following error message (I also tried some other installations but still did not work):

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2251]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Vse pravice pridržane.

C:\Users\lesko>pip install python-weka-wrapper3
Collecting python-weka-wrapper3
  Using cached python_weka_wrapper3-0.2.11-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\lesko\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from python-weka-wrapper3) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\lesko\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from python-weka-wrapper3) (1.21.3)
Collecting python-javabridge>=4.0.0
  Using cached python-javabridge-4.0.3.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in c:\users\lesko\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from packaging->python-weka-wrapper3) (3.0.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: python-javabridge
  Building wheel for python-javabridge (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [43 lines of output]
      C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        warnings.warn(
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge
      copying javabridge\jutil.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge
      copying javabridge\locate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge
      copying javabridge\noseplugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge
      copying javabridge\wrappers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge
      copying javabridge\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\tests
      copying javabridge\tests\test_cpython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\tests
      copying javabridge\tests\test_javabridge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\tests
      copying javabridge\tests\test_jutil.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\tests
      copying javabridge\tests\test_wrappers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\tests
      copying javabridge\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\jars
      copying javabridge\jars\cpython.jar -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\jars
      copying javabridge\jars\rhino-1.7R4.jar -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\jars
      copying javabridge\jars\runnablequeue.jar -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\jars
      copying javabridge\jars\test.jar -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\jars
      running build_ext
      "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\javac.exe" -source 8 -target 8 C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zaly6s0\python-javabridge_43dca1cf6fb64ca588b97ed4a0578461\java\org\cellprofiler\runnablequeue\RunnableQueue.java
      warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
      1 warning
      "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\javac.exe" -source 8 -target 8 C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zaly6s0\python-javabridge_43dca1cf6fb64ca588b97ed4a0578461\java\org\cellprofiler\javabridge\test\RealRect.java
      warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
      1 warning
      "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\javac.exe" -source 8 -target 8 C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zaly6s0\python-javabridge_43dca1cf6fb64ca588b97ed4a0578461\java\org\cellprofiler\javabridge\CPython.java C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zaly6s0\python-javabridge_43dca1cf6fb64ca588b97ed4a0578461\java\org\cellprofiler\javabridge\CPythonInvocationHandler.java
      warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
      Note: C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zaly6s0\python-javabridge_43dca1cf6fb64ca588b97ed4a0578461\java\org\cellprofiler\javabridge\CPythonInvocationHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
      Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
      1 warning
      building 'javabridge._javabridge' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\include\win32" -IC:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" /Tc_javabridge.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\_javabridge.obj
      _javabridge.c
      C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-javabridge
  Running setup.py clean for python-javabridge
Failed to build python-javabridge
Installing collected packages: python-javabridge, python-weka-wrapper3
  Running setup.py install for python-javabridge ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for python-javabridge did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [45 lines of output]
      C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge
      copying javabridge\jutil.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge
      copying javabridge\locate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge
      copying javabridge\noseplugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge
      copying javabridge\wrappers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge
      copying javabridge\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\tests
      copying javabridge\tests\test_cpython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\tests
      copying javabridge\tests\test_javabridge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\tests
      copying javabridge\tests\test_jutil.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\tests
      copying javabridge\tests\test_wrappers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\tests
      copying javabridge\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\jars
      copying javabridge\jars\cpython.jar -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\jars
      copying javabridge\jars\rhino-1.7R4.jar -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\jars
      copying javabridge\jars\runnablequeue.jar -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\jars
      copying javabridge\jars\test.jar -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\javabridge\jars
      running build_ext
      "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\javac.exe" -source 8 -target 8 C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zaly6s0\python-javabridge_43dca1cf6fb64ca588b97ed4a0578461\java\org\cellprofiler\runnablequeue\RunnableQueue.java
      warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
      1 warning
      "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\javac.exe" -source 8 -target 8 C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zaly6s0\python-javabridge_43dca1cf6fb64ca588b97ed4a0578461\java\org\cellprofiler\javabridge\test\RealRect.java
      warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
      1 warning
      "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\javac.exe" -source 8 -target 8 C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zaly6s0\python-javabridge_43dca1cf6fb64ca588b97ed4a0578461\java\org\cellprofiler\javabridge\CPython.java C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zaly6s0\python-javabridge_43dca1cf6fb64ca588b97ed4a0578461\java\org\cellprofiler\javabridge\CPythonInvocationHandler.java
      warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
      Note: C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zaly6s0\python-javabridge_43dca1cf6fb64ca588b97ed4a0578461\java\org\cellprofiler\javabridge\CPythonInvocationHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
      Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
      1 warning
      building 'javabridge._javabridge' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\include\win32" -IC:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" /Tc_javabridge.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\_javabridge.obj
      _javabridge.c
      C:\Users\lesko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> python-javabridge

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

C:\Users\lesko>
```

My system:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.9.7 64 Bit
- Visual Studio Code

What I have already tried:

- pip install nes-py --no-cache-dir
- pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

Answer (score 0):

Instead of compiling from source (always an issue under Windows), you could either install [pre-compiled binaries](https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/install.html#windows) or install through [anaconda](https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/install.html#windows-using-anaconda).

Comment: I have tried it but it does not work! @fracpete

Comment: Please details the exact steps that you performed, from creating your virtual environment to commands executed to install dependencies.